# Data Table not usable on mobile

Tags: html, css, datatable, datatables

```html
<table id="resdatatable" class="table table-striped" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="cursor:pointer">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Booking Date</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Class</th>
      <th>Pick Up</th>
      <th>Duration</th>
      <th>Drop Off</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Coverage</th>
      <th>Quote</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

I am using a Data Table (https://datatables.net) and I am having an issue with it being responsive on mobile.

Here is a screen shot of how it looks on desktop and here's a screen shot of how it looks on mobile:

[image: Mobile]

[image: Desktop]

I can't see the entire other half of the table on mobile. It's the worst. How can I make this responsive and useable on mobile?

Here is the code for the datatable:

Comment: Please create a snippet so we could be try to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question is an Data Tables extension:

https://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/examples/initialisation/responsive.html